# How to print current time in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React project, I want to print current running time. How to get data from time function?

```
const startTime = () => {
        const now = moment();
        const timezone = now.tz(props.timezone)
        const time = timezone.format('h:mm:ss a');
        console.log('CURRENT TIME IS', time)

        const t = setTimeout(function() {
         return startTime()
        }, 1000);
        return t;
      }

     // startTime() shows 32 or 31 or some number
     //I want to print current time here
     console.log('TIME', startTime())
```

I'am getting current time in console. How to print it outside the startTime()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `startTime()` method inside a class. In that case, inside your `render` method call `startTime()` wherever you want to print the current time.

```
render() {
   return <div>
            {this.startTime}
          </div>
}
```

Answer (score -2):

import React from 'react';

```
export class Date extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
var today = new Date(),
date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    this.state = {
            date: date
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.date}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: He asked for time, not data. Right?